# Uploading images to firebase using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I upload image from my PC to Firebase in a web application?

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-file">
    <input type="file" id="img-input" ng-model="img">
</div>
```

**My firebase URL**

```
"https://shopper-fbdbf.firebaseio.com/images"
```

I am not able to get the value of the input in the controller. Is there any other solution? Any api's available for this purpose?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

for use File Api in Angular - 
[ng-file-upload directive](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
// ref - firebase.storage().ref('uploads/' + filename);
    ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
```

});

[This video may faster help you understand how it work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU)